# Как при распаковке ZIP и RAR получить русские названия файлов?

Tags: linux-mint, linux

В архивах ZIP и RAR есть файлы с русскими именами. При распаковке вместо имён кракозяблики. Как сделать, чтобы распаковывалось с понятными именами? MintLinux 12

Comment: Ссылка из ответа: http://kubuntu.ru/node/9352

Answer (score 1):

Zip не хранит кодировку названий файлов, поэтому при распаковке файлов с русскими именами получаются кракозяблы. Можно сначала распаковать, потом переименовать:

```
unzip файлыconvmv -f iso8859-1 -t cp850 -r --notest --nosmart convmv -f cp866 -t utf8 -r --notest --nosmart
```

Answer (score 0):

На Windows и OS X я пользуюсь Zipeg. Только он гарантированно распаковывает русские файлы. Под линуксом можно запустить его через wine.